# Python/MySQL time

Tags: python, mysql, kivy

I have a database in MySQL that stores times. I used the Time datatype to store 4 times. I have a kivy application that will display the times as a string on buttons so that a user can select one of the times. I am trying to convert the times to 12 hour AM/PM times instead of the default 24 hour time format (military time) that MySQL TIME datatypes default to. I am able to get the times from MySQL unto the buttons, but not in the format that I am looking for. I tried to use the SQL `TIME_FORMAT()` method with pymysql to translate the code into the format that I am looking for, but that did not work. For example, I want my time to resemble (10:40:00pm) instead of (22:40:00).

How would I go about doing that? Here is a sample of my Python code below where I gather the times from MySQL and add them to the buttons:

```
def display_times(self):

    cur.execute("""SELECT * FROM appointment_times""")

    times = cur.fetchall()

    time_1 = (times[0])
    time_2 = (times[1])
    time_3 = (times[2])
    time_4 = (times[3])

    form_time_1 = time_1['times']
    form_time_2 = time_2['times']
    form_time_3 = time_3['times']
    form_time_4 = time_4['times']

    self.ids.time_1.text += str(form_time_1)
    self.ids.time_2.text += str(form_time_2)
    self.ids.time_3.text += str(form_time_3)
    self.ids.time_4.text += str(form_time_4)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to get the times in `hh:mm:ss AM/PM` format, you can use `date_format(times, '%r')` in your `select` query (assuming `times` is the time column). The `date_format` function used with `%r` format will convert the time to the desired format (see also https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format).

For example, running the following code:

```
cursor = conn.cursor()
cursor.execute("""select date_format(time_col, '%r') from times""")
times = cursor.fetchall()

time_1 = (times[0])
time_2 = (times[1])
time_3 = (times[2])
time_4 = (times[3])

form_time_1 = time_1[0]
form_time_2 = time_2[0]
form_time_3 = time_3[0]
form_time_4 = time_4[0]

print str(form_time_1)
print str(form_time_2)
print str(form_time_3)
print str(form_time_4)
```

prints the following:

```
11:23:09 AM
07:07:25 PM
03:14:10 AM
08:02:43 PM
```

My `times` table looks like:

```
+----+----------+
| id | time_col |
+----+----------+
|  1 | 11:23:09 |
|  2 | 19:07:25 |
|  3 | 03:14:10 |
|  4 | 20:02:43 |
+----+----------+
```